# How to fix could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-multi-captcha-admin==1.0.0

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to set up a django project on my local. I've created a virtualenv. when I try install the requirements with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\Work\Web Development - Old\PullStream\django\evcs-fe\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lachi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-847c5ux0\\django-multi-captcha-admin_1ab73ac1a6d14606bffcc9cca96b88bf\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lachi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-847c5ux0\\django-multi-captcha-admin_1ab73ac1a6d14606bffcc9cca96b88bf\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lachi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ocge_4v4'
         cwd: C:\Users\lachi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-847c5ux0\django-multi-captcha-admin_1ab73ac1a6d14606bffcc9cca96b88bf\
    Complete output (2 lines):
    error in django-multi-captcha-admin setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
    warning: pypandoc module not found, could not convert Markdown to RST
    ----------------------------------------

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-multi-captcha-admin==1.0.0 (from versions: 1.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-multi-captcha-admin==1.0.0
```

How can I fix this? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This issue tell you that pip repository can't find  the (exact) version of the plugin you want install.**

A workaround is too modify the `requirements.txt` file and take a more generic approach like this :

*Instead of `pip-plugin-name==version-number`*
*do `pip-plugin-name`* , this will install the most up to date version of this plugin hosted on pip server.

**In your case :** replace `django-multi-captcha-admin==1.0.0` by `django-multi-captcha-admin` in the `requirements.txt` file.
If any version of this plugin is present on pip server, it will be installed.

Comment: I thought so. but I'm not sure how it's working fine for my team members same requirements file